# SOCKETS keeping client listening

Tags: java, sockets

I think the problem is that `client 2` is not entering receiving mode and the connection between clients closes before first client sends something to the second... but I might be wrong.

Here is the code of `server` and `clients`. Program is based on token ring algorithm. I'm not fluent in Java so I suppose I didn't use the best way to solve it.

Server:

```
public class TokenServer 
   {
    ServerSocket clientConn;

    public TokenServer(int port){
        System.out.println("Server connecting to port "+port);
        try {
            clientConn = new ServerSocket(port);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 8000;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                port = 8000;
            }
        }
    TokenServer server = new TokenServer(port);



    System.out.println("Server running on port "+port);
    server.listen();
    }

    public void listen(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
            while(true) {
                Socket clientReq = clientConn.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection from "+clientReq.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                serviceClient(clientReq);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
        }
    }

    public void serviceClient(Socket s){
        System.out.println("New request from "+s.getInetAddress());
        ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
        ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;
        int message_id;



        Object message = null;
        try{
            outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            message_id = inStream.readInt();
            System.out.println("Got message "+message_id);

            int zmienna;
            zmienna = message_id + message_id;
            outStream.writeObject(zmienna);

            outStream.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

Client 1:

```
    public class TokenClient1{
    int sendport,recport;
    boolean hasToken = true;
    boolean setSendData = false;
    String host;


    public TokenClient1(String host){
        this.host = host;
    }

    void setSendPort(int sendport)
    {
        this.sendport = sendport;
    }

    void setRecPort(int recport)   
    {
        this.recport = recport;
    }

    public Object sendMessage(int message_id) throws Exception
    {
        Socket serverConn;
        ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
        ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;
        Object response = null;
            serverConn = new Socket(host, sendport);
            outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serverConn.getOutputStream());
            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(serverConn.getInputStream());
            outStream.writeInt(message_id);
            outStream.flush();
            response = inStream.readObject();
            serverConn.close();
            //hasToken = false;
        return response;
    }

    public Object recData() throws Exception
    {
        Socket serverConn;
        ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
        Object response = null;
            serverConn = new Socket(host, recport);
            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(serverConn.getInputStream());
            response = inStream.readObject();
            serverConn.close();


        if(response.toString().equals("Token"))
            {
                hasToken = true;
            }
        return response;
    }



    public static void main (String[] args){

        TokenClient1 client = new TokenClient1("localhost");
        TokenClient1 server = new TokenClient1("localhost");

        client.setSendPort(8002);
        client.setRecPort(8002);
        server.setSendPort(8000);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int wybor, zmienna;
        try{

        while(true)
            {    
        if(client.hasToken == true){
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter the Data --> \n1. YES \n0. NO");
            wybor = scan.nextInt();
            switch (wybor) {
                case 1:
                    {
                        System.out.println("ready to send \n Podaj liczbe do dodania: ");
                        //server.setSendData = true;
                        zmienna = scan.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("odpowiedz servera:");
                        System.out.println((Integer)server.sendMessage(zmienna));
                        break;
                    }
                case 0:
                {
                    System.out.println("i m in else");
                    client.sendMessage(0);
                    client.recData();
                    System.out.println("i m leaving else");
                    break;
                }


            }

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("ENTERING RECEIVING MODE...");
            client.recData();
        }

            }


        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Esception:"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Client 2:

```
    public class TokenClient2
    {
    int sendport,recport;
    boolean hasToken = false;
    String host;
    ServerSocket clientConn;


    public TokenClient2(String host){
        this.host = host;
    }

    void setSendPort(int sendport)
    {
        this.sendport = sendport;
    }

    void setRecPort(int recport)   
    {
        this.recport = recport;
    }

    public Object sendMessage(int message_id) throws Exception
    {
        Socket serverConn;
        ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
        ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;
        Object response = null;
            serverConn = new Socket(host, sendport);
            outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serverConn.getOutputStream());
            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(serverConn.getInputStream());
            outStream.writeInt(message_id);
            outStream.flush();
            response = inStream.readObject();
            serverConn.close();
            //hasToken = false;
        return response;
    }

    void recData() throws Exception
    {
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
          //  while(true) {
        Socket serverConn;

        ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
        Object response = null;
        clientConn = new ServerSocket(8002);
        serverConn = new Socket(host, 8000);
        Socket clientReq = clientConn.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection from "+clientReq.getInetAddress().getHostName());


            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(serverConn.getInputStream());
            response = inStream.readObject();


            clientConn.close();
        System.out.println("Waiting for cents...");

        if(response.equals(0))
            {
                System.out.println("tdfss...");
                hasToken = true;
            }
        //return response;
            }
        //}
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
        }
    }



    public static void main (String[] args){

        TokenClient2 client = new TokenClient2("localhost");
        TokenClient2 server = new TokenClient2("localhost");

        client.setSendPort(8002);
        client.setRecPort(8002);
        server.setSendPort(8000);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int wybor, zmienna;
        try{

        while(true)
            {    
        if(client.hasToken == true){
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter the Data --> \n1. YES \n0. NO");
            wybor = scan.nextInt();
            switch (wybor) {
                case 1:
                    {
                        System.out.println("ready to send \n Podaj liczbe do dodania: ");
                        //server.setSendData = true;
                        zmienna = scan.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("odpowiedz servera:");
                        System.out.println((Integer)server.sendMessage(zmienna));
                        break;
                    }
                case 0:
                {
                    System.out.println("i m in else");
                    client.sendMessage(0);
                    client.recData();
                    System.out.println("i m leaving else");
                    break;
                }


            }

        }
        else {

            client.hasToken=true;
            System.out.println("ENTERING RECEIVING MODE...");
            client.recData();

        }

            }


        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Esception:"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your server returns 2*message_id to the client it came from then it leaves scope without closing the socket. So your client probably never realizes it has been left alone in the dark starving. That's not the token ring I have been taught.

Comment: i used there 2* message_id because im passing there int and i want to execute operation of adding at server and return it to the client1. Most important question is how to make a connect from first to second client when i pick case 0